# Understanding Initial Condition Calculation and Hamilton-Jacobi Equation in Region of Attraction Estimation

Tags: nonlinear-system, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I am currently studying a paper on the determination of regions of attraction for autonomous systems. The paper I'm referring to is available at the following link: [Estimation of the regions of attraction for nonlinear systems.](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Estimation-of-the-regions-of-attraction-for-systems-Yuan-Li/9da52882ab6648aff5644974333f925cf4ea1244)

However, I'm facing difficulty understanding how the initial conditions are calculated and where the Hamilton-Jacobi equation comes into play. The examples provided for determining the region of attraction of a system are somewhat unclear to me. Does anyone have insights or suggestions to clarify these concepts?

For instance, considering the system described by the equations:
$$
\begin{align*}
\dot{x}_1 &= -\sin(x_1) - 0.5 \sin(x_1 - x_2) + 0.01 \\
\dot{x}_2 &= -0.5 \sin(x_2) - 0.5 \sin(x_2 - x_1) + 0.05
\end{align*}
$$
I'm particularly interested in understanding the proposed method for calculating the regions of attraction, as shown in the provided image: 
[image]